# Part of mobile screen not working

Tags: screen

I have an Android mobile **Meizu m5** which has a *Flyme OS*.Until recently the phone has been working just fine. However recently i noticed that the lower part of the screen has stopped working. I tried the touch detector tool and it also didnt work in that specific area which is [image]

On random occasions the screen stated acting weird and clicking random buttons. Antiviruses didnt catch any problem however the antivirus of meizu showeved that there was something in the TouchPal. I transfered my contacts and sms and did a full factory reset however the issue still presisted and then meizus owns antivirus also didnt give any issue.I also took off the screen protector but still no luck.

Waiting for help. Thanks

Comment: If you are willing to resize the screen so as to use only its working part, my answer might help you out. See [Resize screen to display only on working part of semi-functional touchscreen](//android.stackexchange.com/q/115484)

Comment: @Firelord any solution without resizing? As sometimes the whole screen just glitches and clicks random things

Comment: @Talha Usually when a part of the touch screen stops working and a factory reset does not help this is a hardware defect. Therefore I see the three options: 1. resize the screen so that it doe snot use the non-working area. 2. repair the hone (usually means complete new screen) 3. Buy a new phone.

Comment: @Robert but that portion starts working for some times on random occasions. So shouldnt it be a software issue?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem one year ago with m5. I agree that it appears to be a software problem since it sometimes disappear . I bought an M6 and moved on,  but I will send it to service shop since it is still n the warranty period. You can now buy an M8 for the same money

Comment: @magma thanks for your response. So i suppose there is no possible fix

Comment: Well, I think the  only possibility is to send it to a repair center and see what happens. I will do it asap since my 2 year EU warranty is expiring soon. They will keep it for 30-40 days they told me. That's why I bought a new model in the meantime

Comment: @magma oh ok well mabye i'll try to do the same.Thanks